# Can we use Power BI to generate reports from SharePoint 2013 ON-PREMISE data (list and libraries)?

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, sharepoint-integration, powerbi

There are a lot of articles talking about integration of Power BI with SharePoint online.
Can we use **Power BI** to generate reports from **SharePoint 2013 ON-PREMISE** data (list and libraries) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you need the On-Premise Gateway running on a server on your network. Power BI accesses it through the gateway.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Can you please mention some suggested links having the details of the same ?

Comment: It's on the Power BI site when you log in. At the top right, where you see a series of icons, click the one that looks like an arrow pointing down at a line. The drop down menu has an option for Data Gateway.

Comment: Be aware that there are two gateways - Personal and Enterprise. Personal GW is used only for one user and is running only when the user is signed in to PC. Enterprise gateway is running as Windows Service and is supposed to be used for all users but it requires Pro license for all users accessing the reports.